# How to use the stdin as a file

Tags: bash, shell-script, osx, zsh, stdin

I have a command that wants a file as input, but I get the input from the `stdin` and I don't want to create a temporary file.

I would like to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
osadecompile /dev/stdin < input_file.scpt
```

but that causes an I/O error. The followingworks, but is it possible *without* using a temporary intermediate file_?

```
#!/bin/bash
AS_FILE=$(mktemp)
cat - > "$AS_FILE"
osadecompile "$AS_FILE"
rm "$AS_FILE"
```

As you might have guessed, I'm on macOS with **bash 3.2**. However, a **zsh 5.3** solution would also be welcomed.

Comment: Does `osadecompile <(cat -)` work?

Comment: Possibly `osadecompile` needs the file to be seekable.

Comment: In `zsh` you could also use `osadecompile =(cat -)`. This actually creates a temporary file and removes it automatically when the command exits.

Comment: Wouldn't `&$1` or `$1` work for input? A bit like feeding some program a file, url, or whatever. Just a thought.

Comment: `<(cat -)` fails in bash, because of bug in bash 3.2. I wouldn't know how to use `&$1` or `$1`... The `osadecompile =(cat -)` zsh option works. Can you make that an answer, so I can accept it? Also: what is the `=()` in zsh and `<()` in bash constructs called? I tried to look for it, but it wasn't mentioned in the redirect chapter of the manual...

Comment: @doekman `<(...)` in bash is called [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). I imagine the same term is used in zsh as well.

Comment: @doekman zsh seems to also like [Command Substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html), which also covers `=(...)`.

Comment: @doekman Can you post the solution that worked for you on this platform?

Comment: @Dejan I ended up [using a temp-file](https://github.com/doekman/osagitfilter/blob/master/osagitfilter.sh#L157). That works just fine. I was learning about bash, so that's why I was pursuing a "better" way to do it. Now I guess if you want a clean script, you perhaps better use `zsh`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
cmd =(cat)
```

Where `=(...)` is a third form of process substitution that uses a temporary files instead of a pipe.

With `bash` versions prior to 5.1 or `zsh`, for input that doesn't end in empty lines (and in bash that doesn't contain NUL bytes), you can do:

```
cmd /dev/fd/3 3<<< "$(cat)"
```

As here-strings (that come from zsh) like here documents (that come from the Bourne shell) are implemented with (deleted) temporary files in both bash¹ and zsh. On macOS (as opposed to Linux), that assumes, `cmd` opens the file only once (it's free to seek within it though), as each opening would start at the same position within the file as left at the preceding opening which would likely confuse `cmd` if it assumes the position is at the start of the file.

---

<sup>¹ note that bash behaviour changed in 5.0 where bash started to go out of its way to make the temporary file non-writable, and in 5.1 where it switched to using pipes instead of temporary files for small ones</sup>